# MyTouch upgraded to Froyo now requires reboot to use USB storage again

Tags: 2.2-froyo

After T-Mobile upgraded my "original MyTouch 3G" to Froyo, I have to reboot the phone to reconnect it to my computer after it's been connected once and disconnected.

I've tried using different USB ports on my computer, and everything else I can think of.  Is there a fix for this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Are you properly dismounting the phone storage from your computer, and then having your phone mount it, before disconnecting USB?

Comment: That did it.  I was pulling the plug whenever I was ready.  If you'll put this as an answer I'll mark it as "the" answer.  Thanks a lot.  (Funny that I never had to do this routine before the upgrade.  Oh well, I'm glad to have a "fix".)

Comment: Done, glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you properly dismount the phone storage from your computer, and then have your phone mount it, before disconnecting USB.